# Removing properties from an object but preserving type

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have an arbitrary object:

```
const foo = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3};
```

and I want to remove the `bar` property. This I can do with a function like:

```
function omission<T extends {}, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  remove: K
): Omit<T, K> {
  const { [remove]: _, ...without } = obj;
  return without;
}
```

This does indeed remove both a property from the type system and the run time system. Yay. But I want to be able to remove an arbitrary number of props. I was hoping a little recursion would do the trick but I'm struggling to get it to work. Here's my attempt:

```
export function omit<T extends {}, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...removals: K[]
) {
  if (removals.length === 0) {
    return obj;
  }
  const omitted = omission(obj, removals[0]);
  const remaining = (removals.slice(1) as unknown) as Array<keyof typeof omitted>;

  return remaining.length > 0 ? omit(omitted, remaining) : omitted;
}
```

Not surprisingly it *does* work with the runtime system but the type system gives up. Admittedly my forced typing attempt was desperation but i'm desperate. Anyone know how to get this utility out of the garage?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AHgCoBooGkoQB7AQB2AJgM5QDWEIA9gGZSoB8UAvFAAoIDGlamAKJ4eAGwCuJCMmp1GGbM2YBuALAAoDQHotUMgiIBzcaICGAJyhhztMFHMQ4tAG6nRG+uKI9gCWkShaRDJ9fzRcAmJyKABvAF9MHHxCUgpZBiZ2KhoMlgAKDShAgCMAKwAuJnRC+0cXCEqsDQBKSvgkAUVYmp5-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-I2XV-UvURAnocKwygAByKTzGKqyPVADQ+KgbFRHoAB1F0lxlFc8lEzBSosYrdxqvpaAlDtaEMPIYnqpqXTiPrNA07KkVipyKB9bFxigAADBwSHEHhA3W30TPHeFES03gyX8URiWxDEoAAIlE27KrBaq5vpByKEchxekMWiFPgwUoqIABaXw4t9LL7VFRKiuZU9FXUWqtp2+COEBDrBK6srisxxTer2A9BogYbRpiJHdpIaa9jYpAoBIWgeUWWhzEoJEBnMLxQegIGgagD8BjIY5rBlU8oG58GpWgWHjXoHEoXGcxwtMEhkMuqBbyIaAZIATiWrEIDBWnIQ9QV4yAA)

Comment: I can't think of any possible way except accepting each type as a separate param. [See this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHAtjKAeAKogpgDylzABMBnRAbwF8AaRAaT0OPMQGtcBPOYRLegFlmRUhU48+AxADkRrcd178AfAAo4AIwBWALmkSAjLsb0JAJhOCz3AMwmZAShMB5NJmlMAPomE+ZKgCwAFCgkLAIyO7Y8mJUdIyxbBLK0sIEoslKUupaegbcxqYc3Ja+zohu6Nj03r5BoeDQ8Eio1TgZCvG1SYqSqho6+jZcRQwVVR61DWHNkW0evd2JnXEpUogAvCX9WLlD-LQAdCcATrgocABuAIYANmQmDADaALqOVCGIiAD0P4gwFAABzuF2IUABEK+iHOUBAp1aOhC1BCIQgCDIEOAcDgWyo2LgJkM9E0N1OJnMJJuAC8TLZqABuVHBdFgTEw3AkEAQTl4hZqAn0ADkpNOQuFpOpQscTOC5y5PJIR1FQA)

Comment: As an option `removals.reduce((a:Omit<T, K> ,c) =>{ const { [c]: _, ...without } = a; return without as Omit<T, K>}, obj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the keys are completely dynamic, I don't think there's a way to do this without using type assertion *somewhere*.

Instead of recursion, I think it'd be easier to filter the object's entries by whether the array of keys includes the key, then turn it back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```
function omit<T extends {}, K extends Array<keyof T>>(
  obj: T,
  ...removals: K
) {
  // workaround for TypeScript's bad .includes typing:
  // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255
  const removalsUntyped = removals as Array<unknown>;
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([key]) => !removalsUntyped.includes(key))
  ) as Omit<T, K[number]>;
}

const foo = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 };
const reduced = omit(foo, 'bar', 'baz');
console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.